# How can I pass values to the url VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble changing the url in this line of code

```
 <div id="pointer_div" runat="server" onmousemove="over_it(event)" onclick="point_it(event)" style = " border:1px solid green;width:559px;height:385px;">
```

`pointer_div.Style.Add("background-image", "url(http://www.test.com/cgis/images/" + m_IncidentLocationName` + "/" + m_IncidentZoneID + ".gif )")

I'm getting those values from the session file as string

```
 m_IncidentLocationName 
  m_IncidentZoneID
```

how can I set it up correctly?

Comment: when you say you're having trouble does that mean the code errors at runtime or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

Add a new variable after your m_IncidentLocationName and m_IncidentZoneID variables as follows:

```
Dim URL as String
URL = String.Format("url(http://www.test.com/cgis/images/{0}/{1}.gif)", m_IncidentLocationName, m_IncidentZoneID)
```

Now Modify your code as follows:

```
pointer_div.Style.Add("background-image", URL)
```

You should bear in mind that this will likely replace any existing styles that are set on the style attribute.

To reinstate those you may have to re-add them someting like:

```
Dim styles as String
styles = " border:1px solid green;width:559px;height:385px;"

pointer_div.Style.Add("background-image", URL & styles)
```

Good luck!